# show and hide jquery bootstrap

Tags: jquery, popup, bootstrap-modal, hide, show

I am trying to make a modal pop-up in bootstrap4 I followed the instructions to open it, then I tried to add  hide jquery  to close the pop-up after y seconds, but it did not work. I made a mistake somewhere
button trigger

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" id="myBtn">Pop-up manual trigger </button>
```

pop-up

```
     <div class="modal fade" id="exModal1button" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="anim">
          <p>Your text ...bla bla... and so on!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myBtn").click(function(){
    $("#exModal1button").modal("show");
});
    $("exModal1button").hide(5000);});
```

Comment: `then I tried to add hide jquery to close the pop-up after y seconds`  where?  All i see is you hiding the button on page load with a 5 second duration. (Ref. http://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-duration-complete)

Comment: Yes in your code you hide the button, and not the modal.

Comment: Probably is that you importing jquery after of bootstrap or you don't importing all necessary files. To use Bootstrap4 you need some files to work properly.

Comment: I have put jquery right before the ending body tag, also I have another jquery sxcript before this one, and it works w/o problem

Answer (score 0):

May be due to mistake in this line.

```
$("exModal1button").hide(5000);});
```

an extra closing curly braces.

And you can do like this.

```
$('#exModal1Button').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){$('#exModal1Button').hide();},5000);
    // OR
    setTimeout(function(){$('#exModal1Button').modal('hide');},5000);
})
```

Comment: Thx. I tried both, no results at all. The pop-up opens when button is clicked, but it doesn't close after the time set -5000 ms-

Comment: Sorry @mrs68tm there was a mistake in my solution. I have edited my answer

Comment: hi, after some trials and errors with ur piece of code, I found a way to make it work, I add in the div of the modal   the following :   data-backdrop="true"